# Balanced smileys check algorithm (part 2)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, balanced-delimiters

This is a follow-up for [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152739/balanced-smileys-check-algorithm).

> **Problem**
>
> Your friend John uses a lot of emoticons when you talk to him on
>   Messenger. In addition to being a person who likes to express himself
>   through emoticons, he hates unbalanced parenthesis so much that it
>   makes him go :(
>
> Sometimes he puts emoticons within parentheses, and you find it hard
>   to tell if a parenthesis really is a parenthesis or part of an
>   emoticon.
>
> A message has balanced parentheses if it consists of one of the
>   following:
>
> - An empty string ""
> - One or more of the following characters: 'a' to 'z', ' ' (a space) or ':' (a colon)
> - An open parenthesis '(', followed by a message with balanced parentheses, followed by a close parenthesis ')'.
> - A message with balanced parentheses followed by another message with balanced parentheses.
> - A smiley face ":)" or a frowny face ":("
> - Write a program that determines if there is a way to interpret his message while leaving the parentheses balanced.

I'm working on this balanced smileys checking algorithm, and my current solution is very naive, with just two rules:

1. At any point, the number of `)` (close) should be less than the number of `(` (open) + number of `:(` (frown)
2. At the end, the number of `(` (open) should be less than the number of `)` (close) and `:)` (smile)

I'm wondering if any bugs in my checking logic. Any advice on algorithm time complexity improvement or code style advice is highly appreciated as well.

```
def check_balance(source):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    frown = 0
    smile = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(source):
        if c == '(':
            left += 1
            if i > 0 and source[i-1] == ':': # :(
                left -= 1
                frown += 1
        elif c == ')':
            right += 1
            if i > 0 and source[i-1] == ':': # :)
                right -= 1
                smile += 1
                if left + frown < right:
                    return False
    if left > right + smile:
        return False
    return True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_smile_string = 'abc(b:)cdef(:()'
    print check_balance(raw_smile_string)
```

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions on Code Review. Please do a better job picking tags for your questions. In this case, since you're asking a follow-up question, it should have been obvious which tags to use.

Comment: @200_success, would love to follow your advice, for follow-up question, what is the suggested tag?

Comment: Well, I added [tag:balanced-delimiters] to the previous question, so obviously it should apply to this question too.

Comment: @200_success, for sure, thanks. Is it possible I can add some tags? So that if I post different version of code, I can refer old post by tag (from the new version of code post)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the verbal description of the algorithm, "should be less than" implies "not equal", which would not be correct. A wording such as "must be at most" would be totally clear.
- Your code has a bug because you are not quite following rule 1. The rule says "at any point...", but you only check the rule after a smiley. You miss the case when a lone `)` breaks the rule.
- Instead of canceling `+= 1` with `-= 1` here...

  ```
  left += 1
  if i > 0 and source[i-1] == ':': # :(
      left -= 1
      frown += 1
  ```

  ... it would be clearer to use `else`:

  ```
  if i > 0 and source[i-1] == ':': # :(
      frown += 1
  else:
      left += 1
  ```
- Instead of `if i > 0 and source[i-1] == ':'` it would be simpler to remember the previous character in a variable:

  ```
   previous_char = None 
   for char in source:
       if char == 'c':
           if previous_char == ':':
       ...
       previous_char = char
  ```

Comment: instead of manually setting the previous character in a variable, it would be clearer to use the [`itertools`' `pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Good idea, but then checking if the first character of the string is `(` or `)` would be a special case.

Comment: Not necessarily, you just need to adapt `pairwise`: `a, b = tee(iterable); yield next(a), None; yield from zip(a, b)`. And you iterate over with `for char, previous in …`.

Comment: Thanks Janne, I post a new thread (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154783/balanced-smileys-check-algorithm-part-2) to address your comments, if you have advice on that, it will be great. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

- Variable naming

  - Can be greatly improved by the use of an IDE like IDEA which supports trivial variable renaming.
  - Don't use single character variables, `index` and `character` (or even `char`) is much more readable than `i` and `c`.
  - It's not *immediately obvious* what any of the variables are.
- You only have one test case. There should be test cases including and excluding each of the types of content of a message. If you get started with the simplest one you can even use TDD to get to a working but simple design.
- Knowing the index of the unbalanced parenthesis would be nice.
- Checking the number of parentheses is not enough, you have to whether they match up. For example, your algorithm fails (reports True when it shouldn't) on strings like `)(`.
- The assignment calls for a recursive solution:

  > A message has balanced parentheses if it consists of one of the following: […] An open parenthesis '(', followed by a message with balanced parentheses, followed by a close parenthesis ')'.

  This means that within each pair of parentheses there must be a valid message, meaning all the rules apply within them.

Comment: Hi l0b0, I have the same question from @JanneKarila, if you could help to clarify, it will be great.

Comment: Hi l0b0, are there any code logical bug (for logical, I mean my code returns wrong conclusion about True/False for balance or not) in my posted code?

Comment: I **did** post an example of input leading to the wrong conclusion. And which "same question" do you refer to?

Comment: Thanks l0b0, I think you mean the example of `)(`?

Comment: BTW  l0b0, I post a new thread (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154783/balanced-smileys-check-algorithm-part-2) to address your comments, if you have advice on that, it will be great. Vote up for all of your comments.